# Watermark Testing using Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am testing an web application. There is an employee registration UI in the application. I want to test that all the watermarks displayed in the UI are correct using selenium web driver.Which is the command used to read watermark values?.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Yhy.jpg)

Comment: are you referring place holder as water mark

Comment: I think so.,I am a Test Engineer not a developer

Comment: can you please post the source code for the page so that i can help you

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i am thinking right then plz do it like below suppose the html source code of the page that you want to work on is like below

**HTML Source**

```
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 1">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 2">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 3">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 4">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 5">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 6">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 7">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 8">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 9">
 <input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search this website 10">
```

then please do it like below

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("file:///C:/Users/rajnish/Desktop/inpuBox.html");
        // take everything inside the list like below
        List<WebElement> myInputBoxes = driver.findElements(By.name("s"));
        // now to print the place holder run a for loop 
        for(int i=0;i<myInputBoxes.size();i++){
            System.out.println("PlaceHolder is : " + myInputBoxes.get(i).getAttribute("placeholder"));
        }
    }
}
```